# PreparedStatement Value Error in java

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, mssql-jdbc

The fallowing code is giving "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'." I can not find the problem with my SQL statement.

/*
                 * Table Structure for HistoryData Table in SQL Server
                 * 1) City_ID - int
                 * 2)City_Name - nvarchar(50)
                 * 3)Time - datetime
                 * 4)Received_Time - datetime
                 * 5)Humidity - float
                 * 6)Rain_info - float
                 * 7)Snow_info - float
                 * 8)Temperature - float
                 * 9)Min_Temperature - float
                 * 10)Max_Temperature - float
                 * 11)Description - nvarchar(50)
                */

```
            try 
            {
                String statementString = "INSERT INTO WeatherHistoryX("
                     +"City_ID,"
                     +"City_Name,"
                     +"Time,"
                     +"Received_Time,"
                     +"Humdity,"
                     +"Rain_Info,"
                     +"Snow_Info,"
                     +"Temperature,"
                     +"Min_Temperature,"
                     +"Max_Temperature,"
                     +"Description,"
                     +"VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

                pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(statementString);

                //statement = null;
                //statement = connection.createStatement();

                java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(weather.getDate());
                java.sql.Date currentSqlDate = new java.sql.Date(currentTimestamp.getTime());                   

                pStatement.setInt(1, weather.getCityCode());
                pStatement.setString(2, weather.getCity());
                pStatement.setDate(3, sqlDate);
                pStatement.setDate(4, currentSqlDate);
                pStatement.setFloat(5, weather.getHumidity());
                pStatement.setFloat(6, weather.getRainInfo());
                pStatement.setFloat(7, weather.getSnowInfo());
                pStatement.setFloat(8, weather.getTemperature());
                pStatement.setFloat(9, weather.getMinTemperature());
                pStatement.setFloat(10, weather.getMaxTemperature());
                pStatement.setString(11, weather.getDescription());

                pStatement.execute();
```

Comment: There's a comma too much before the `VALUES`.

Comment: ... and a bracket is missing. Consider writing SQL queries in a dedicated SQL editor. Debugging in Java code is tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra "," after Description.

Just remove that comma and add ")" and a space.